# Issue with Kendo Graph in Printing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We have a page where we are printing Kendo pie charts which is working perfectly fine. We have a facility to print these charts using default windows Print option using Windows.Print(). Issue that we have seen is that the charts which are Center aligned shifts to right while we are printing. On investingating further we understood that this is happening because the page is resizing itself while Printing but Kendo Charts are not resizing and aligning themselves in center. We explicitely refreshed the Kendo charts by adding followed by explicit refresh of Kendo Chart

```
$(“#Chart”).data("kendoChart").refresh();
```

However still we are facing challenge while getting it center aligned while printing. Has anyone faced similar challenge? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize kendo chart by redraw method

```
$("#myChart").data("kendoChart").redraw();
```